# Write a query to get rid of duplicate records in oracle database with below mentioned criteria:

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, duplicates, sql-update

Criteria :
1) unique combination of 2 columns(column1,column2)

2) keep oldest one out of that combination

3) records might be same i.e. same column1, column2 and creation date in that case need the one which has lesser id.

e.g. data is as below:

```
ID      column1     column2     creation_date(dd-mm-yyyy)       
1       11          aa          10/5/2016
2       11          aa          11/6/2016
3       12          bb          10/5/2017
4       12          bb          20-05-2017
5       12          cc          10/5/2016
6       12          cc          11/5/2017
7       13          dd          10/1/2018
8       13          dd          10/1/2018
```

I need to keep records with id: 1,3,5,7

Approach I am thinking of is:

a) first write select query to get required records (in this example 1,3,5,7)

b) write update query to change status to deleted using update query(soft delete)

Also please suggest if any other better approach to fulfill the criteria.

Additional information: 
*total number of records: 11k

*I don't want to get records directly from table rather than that I have a query which fetches only required data, need to run query on those records

*Final aim is to modify status of duplicate records to deleted and append deleted word to those records

Answer (score 0):

This is really straight forward if you use analytic functions. The query has three parts:

A) Assign a rank to each record like this:
   Group records by column1 and column2. Within each group, sort the records first by creation_date and then by ID. Assign 1 to the first record, 2 to the second and so on.

B) Keep only the duplicates, i.e. the records with newer creation_date and/or ID. The record with rnk = 1 would be your requested record. Records with rnk > 1 are the duplicates.

C) Using ROWID, delete the duplicates

```
delete
  from your_table
 where rowid in(-- (C) 
        select duplicate_rowid
          from (select rowid as duplicate_rowid
                      ,row_number() over( -- (A) 
                         partition by column1, column2    -- Your criterion 1
                             order by creation_date asc   -- Your criterion 2
                                     ,id            asc   -- Your criterion 3
                      ) as rnk
                  from your_table
                )
         where rnk > 1  -- (B) 
       );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it's working fine. But right now instead of 'my_table' I want to use another query which is giving me only desired records from 'my_table'. When I tried to use query instead of 'my_table' it's not working.  Note: that total number of records are 11k and my query is giving me 8k records, on which i want to perform update action of changing the status to 'deleted'.

Comment: Also can I use a PL-SQL block to loop on my query result? as ultimate goal to update duplicate records with deleted status. or any other way to achieve this. If yes, please suggest.

Comment: Please update the question with enough details, and I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Please check if these details modified in question are sufficient or do you need any other information?

Comment: You can change DELETE to UPDATE

Comment: Slight modification, I need non null column1, column2 values. Right now null values are coming in result. Can you please tell where can I put NOT NULL condition?

Comment: Got the solution. Everything is working as expected. Thanks a ton for help Ronnis.

Answer (score 0):

So final queries which worked for my question are as below:

1) to get count of records/ to get required columns:

```
SELECT --count (*) -use this to get count of records
ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2,CREATION_DATE --required columns
FROM
MY_TABLE
WHERE
ROWID IN( 
        select duplicate_rowid 
          from (select rowid as duplicate_rowid
                      ,row_number() over(  
                         partition by COLUMN1, COLUMN2      --  criterion 1
                             ORDER BY CREATION_DATE ASC   -- criterion 2
                                     ,ID   ASC          -- criterion 3

                      ) AS RNK
                  from MY_TABLE
                )
         WHERE (RNK > 1 and COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL and COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL)
);
```

2) to update records with status=deleted and append _deleted word to column1 values:

```
    UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET STATUS='deleted' , COLUMN1=CONCAT(COLUMN1,'_deleted') 
    WHERE
    ROWID IN( 
                select duplicate_rowid 
                  from (select rowid as duplicate_rowid
                              ,row_number() over(  
                                 partition by COLUMN1, COLUMN2      --  criterion 1
                                     ORDER BY CREATION_DATE ASC   -- criterion 2
                                             ,ID   ASC          -- criterion 3

                              ) AS RNK
                          from MY_TABLE
                        )
                 WHERE (RNK > 1 and COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL and COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL)
);
```